# Probability of picking from categories with repeated trys

Tags: probability

Maybe this is a stupid question but I can't seem to find any examples of this scenario on the internet. If you can direct me to somewhere this type of problem is solved that would be helpful. :)

> There are 9 blue balls and 11 red balls in a jar. If you pick *n* balls from the jar, with replacement, what is the probability of picking at least *m* red balls in terms of *m* and *n*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a simple binomial question.  The probability of picking exactly k red balls is $\binom{n}{k}(\frac{11}{20})^k (\frac{9}{20})^{n-k}$  To get what you want, sum k from m to n.